# Haskell bind with multiple monads

Tags: haskell, nested, pattern-matching, bind

Right now my code looks like this:

```
postUser :: ServerPart Response
postUser = do
  -- parseBody :: ServerPart (Maybe User)
  parsedUser <- parseBody
  case parsedUser of
    Just user -> do
      -- saveUser :: User -> ServerPart (Maybe (Key User))
      savedUser <- saveUser user
      case savedUser of
        Just user -> successResponse
        Nothing   -> errorResponse "user already exists"
    Nothing   -> errorResponse "couldn't parse user"
```

Which works, but I know there's a way to avoid the nested pattern matching. I thought this was what bind would do for me, so I tried

```
parseUser :: ServerPart (Maybe User)
addUser :: User -> ServerPart (Maybe ())
case parseUser >>= saveUser of
  Just _  -> success
  Nothing -> error
```

and

```
savedUser <- (parseUser >>= saveUser)
case savedUser of
  Just _  -> success
  Nothing -> error
```

But I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’ with ‘User’
    Expected type: Maybe a0 -> ServerPartT IO (Maybe (Key User))
      Actual type: User -> ServerPart (Maybe (Key User))
    In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘saveUser’
    In the expression: parseBody >>= saveUser
```

which I take to mean `>>=` is applying `saveUser` to the `Maybe User` instead of the `User` that I need it to, and I'm not sure how to finagle the types to match.
How can I rewrite this to avoid the nested pattern matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would argue that the original way you have it written is the most readable approach, taking this as an exercise, the MaybeT monad transformer is what you are looking for.

The problem you are running into is that your are trying to jump between the ServerPart monad and the Maybe monad.  This is why you can't directly bind parseBody and saveUser.  Monad transformers allow you to combine monads to avoid this problem.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

postUser :: ServerPart Response
postUser = do
  -- parseBody :: MaybeT ServerPart User
  -- saveUser :: User -> MaybeT ServerPart (Key User)
  user <- runMaybeT $ parseBody >>= saveUser
  case user of
    Just _ -> successResponse
    Nothing -> errorResponse "Error saving user"
```

You will need to refactor your parseBody and saveUser functions to use the MaybeT monad.  Since I can't see these functions, I can't help you there, but it can usually be done easily using `lift` from Control.Applicative.

Useful links on monad transformers:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers
https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/commercial/content/monad-transformers

EDIT: MaybeT for parseBody

```
parseBody :: FromJSON a => MaybeT ServerPart a
parseBody = MaybeT $ fmap A.decode getBody
```

And just as a general tip: `bar >>= (return . f)` is equivalent to `fmap f bar`.  The latter being cleaner and more general since it does not require the monad instance.

Comment: that totally worked, now like you mentioned I'm trying to convert `parseBody` to use MaybeT, which I'm also having trouble with. I feel like I'm close, but still can't get types to match up right

https://gist.github.com/feighter09/be2afa1fb6cb810f9e1c24d79882caf8

Comment: Why did you change `ServerPart` to `ServerPartT IO`?

Comment: `ServerPart` is an alias for `ServerPartT IO`, and when I had it as `parseBody :: FromJSON a => MaybeT ServerPart a`, I was getting the error: `Type synonym ‘ServerPart’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none`
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.4.6.1/docs/Happstack-Server-Internal-Monads.html#t:ServerPart

Comment: Figured it out. Got `parseBody` and `saveUser` converted to using `MaybeT` and this works beautifully. Still curious why you think the original version would be better, this exhibits the Railway Oriented Programming I was hoping to achieve

Comment: It did end up being more graceful than I expected. But you do lose the differentiation of your error messages.

Comment: In this case yes, but I really should be using something like `Either User ErrorType`, to propogate errors, which would solve that too